# Efficient way to scroll to certain index in FlatList with variable item size

Tags: react-native

I'm having a trouble adding scroll/jump to certain index functionality on FlatList in react-native. My FlatList items are vary in size (height) which makes me unable to implement `getItemLayout` since this requires me to have prior knowledge about the FlatList item size, therefore I cannot use `scrollToIndex` (which requires `getItemLayout` to be implemented).

My solution was to get each item's size when rendered by using `onLayout` and map them with their index. I can then use each item size to get their offset and use `scrollToOffset` to jump to the given item (by using `scrollToItem` function in the code below). The issue here is that I am not able to jump to certain item until that item has been rendered.
My temporary solution for that is by tweaking `initialNumberToRender` close to the number of data and set the `windowSize` props as high as possible so that all of the items will be rendered (even though the user doesn't scroll down).

```
getOffsetByIndex = (index) => {
    let offset = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < index; i++) {
      const elementLayout = this.layoutMap[index];
      if (elementLayout && elementLayout.height) {
        offset += this.layoutMap[i].height;
      }
    }
    return offset;
};

scrollToItem = (index) => {
  const offset = this.getOffsetByIndex(index);
  this.flatListRef.scrollToOffset(offset);
};

addToLayoutMap = (layout, index) => {
  this.layoutMap[index] = layout;
};

render(){
  return(
    <FlatList
      ref={this.flatListRef}
      data={this.state.data}
      renderItem={() => <View onLayout={this.addToLayoutMap}> <SomeComponent/> </View>}
      initialNumToRender={this.state.data.length / 5}
      windowSize={this.state.data.length}
    />
  );
}
```

This solution works with small number of data, but when the data is large (containing ~300 of rows), it will take long time to be rendered get all the item size, preventing the user to jump to the last item directly for example.

Is there any efficient way to do it?
Also, rendering all the rows is so memory consumptive and negates the benefit of using FlatList.

Comment: Split your data and load them on scroll. Try to scroll to latest visible and possible index. Then use `onScrollToIndexFailed` prop to scroll again to desired index. I can have sample for you if this didn't work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can dynamically split your data according to scroll direction. If scroll goes up prepend data to your state and same for opposite direction. Then use `onScrollToIndexFailed` like this :

```
<FlatList
  ref={this.flatListRef}
  data={this.state.data}
  renderItem={() => <View> <SomeComponent /> </View>}
  initialNumToRender={this.state.data.length / 5}
  onEndReached={(e) => {
    // Append data
  }}
  onScroll={(e) => {
    if (e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y == 0) {
      // Prepend data
    }
  }}
  onScrollToIndexFailed={(error) => {
    this.flatListRef.scrollToOffset({ offset: error.averageItemLength * error.index, animated: true });
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.state.data.length !== 0 && this.flatListRef !== null) {
        this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({ index: error.index, animated: true });
      }
    }, 100);
  }}
/>
```

You can workaround this issue. This worked for me and took me a lot of time to get that work :))

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Let me try to digest and try it later. A quick question tho, you are suggesting me to use `scrollToIndex`? Since `onScrollToIndexFailed` is called when failed to scroll to particular index. I think using `scrollToIndex` requires `getItemLayout` to be implemented, which in my current case cant be done accurately due to varied item's size

Comment: No `scrollToIndex` does not depend on `getItemLayout`. You can use scrollToIndex anytime you want!

Comment: @user1677104 Notice: Please remove  `initialNumToRender` :( That may cause performance problems

Comment: well noted, thanks for your answer, will post follow up result once I have given it a try. Currently having build problem

Comment: hi, I've tried it, the problem is, when I try to scroll to index of the data that hasn't been fetched, I got scrollToIndex out of range error, since the initial data hasn't been appended. So the `onScrollToIndexFailed` isn't even executed here since FlatList first checks for the length of the data, if the desired index is within the range of the data, it would then try to scroll to it and execute `onScrollToIndexFailed` when the index in fact hasn't been rendered. How do you work around this issue?

Comment: I end up using `scrollToIndex` and use `onScrollToIndexFailed` like what you provided. I didn't split my data as what you suggested due to issue I mentioned above, still gives some stutter, but tolerable.

Comment: @user1677104 Wait for async task to finish then initialize and scroll.

Comment: Hi there, I am trying something similar with `scrollToIndex` but its `viewOffset` got me stumped. the list should scroll up to and stop above `Keyboard` however, for the first couple of items on the list, the `viewOffset` value pushes them up, whereas scrolling down the list item and keyboard shows up, it behaves correctly. I am not sure how can I control the `viewOffset`

Comment: May I know how could you figure out the `setTimeout` time as 100ms

Comment: @Kishore You can set them after setState callback and remove `setTimeout`

Comment: @MatinZD Ok, But I am calling `ScroToIndex' after app state update as I have `FlatList` data in app state. what Can I do in this case?

Comment: @Kishore Please post your code somewhere so I can see that

Comment: You save my day, @MatinZD. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Man this finally worked for me after failing for 2 hours!

Comment: It takes me more than a year to realize that onScrollToIndexFailed is this useful. Thanks man. It works...

Comment: You are a lifesaver bro. I was really stuck at it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MatinZadehDolatabad what do you mean by split data?

Comment: FYI: within onScrollToIndexFailed, all I needed was the `setTimeout(() => {` block, I didn't need to call `this.flatListRef.scrollToOffset()`
Also, I did not need to specify the 100ms timeout.