# How to go to a specific item(index) in FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57471165/efficient-way-to-scroll-to-certain-index-in-flatlist-with-variable-item-size), but I could not do.
I have a static list named DAYS and bind it to the FlatList as below :

```
const DAYS = [
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
]

const App = () => {
  const onViewRef = useRef((viewableItems) => {
  })

  const viewConfigRef = useRef({ viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 50 })

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>

      <Button title="Go To" onPress={() => { }} />
      <FlatList
        data={DAYS}
        horizontal={true}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        onViewableItemsChanged={onViewRef.current}
        viewabilityConfig={viewConfigRef.current}
        renderItem={({ item }) =>
          <View style={styles.textContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{item}</Text>
          </View>}
      />

    </View>
  )
}
```

after running :

[image]

Now, when I click on the button(GO TO), FlatList should be as below :

**(for example go to item 10,Selected Item should be center)**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By reading [scrollToIndex](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html#scrolltoindex) and [getItemLayout](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html#getitemlayout) probably you can do:

```js
const DAYS = [
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
]

const ITEM_WIDTH = 20 // size of you element

const App = () => {
  const flatListRef = useRef(null)

  const onViewRef = useRef((viewableItems) => {
  })

  const viewConfigRef = useRef({ viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 50 })

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>

      <Button title="Go To" onPress={() => {
        if (flatListRef.current) {
            flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({index: 9}) // Scroll to day 10
        }
      }} />
      <FlatList

        ref={flatListRef} // add ref
        getItemLayout={(data, index) => (
          {length: ITEM_WIDTH, offset: ITEM_WIDTH * index, index}
        )}

        data={DAYS}
        horizontal={true}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        onViewableItemsChanged={onViewRef.current}
        viewabilityConfig={viewConfigRef.current}
        renderItem={({ item }) =>
          <View style={styles.textContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{item}</Text>
          </View>}
      />

    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: thanks . after clicking on the button I get error : ``scrollToIndex out of range: requested index undefined but maximum is 29``

Comment: I just updated the answer. should be `scrollToIndex({index: 9})` NOT `scrollToIndex(9)`

Comment: After the clicking the button, Item 10 will be the first element in the FlatList, Is it possible to get centered (like the image above)? (http://uupload.ir/files/920j_primary.png)

Comment: You should play with offset.