# How to save the scroll position of flatlist and navigate back to the same position in React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to implement a list of items in flatlist where -> on clicking of item it goes to detail page -> on navigating back I would want the flatlist to be in the same position.

However whenever I navigate back, the flatlist is always pointing to the top item, also a white space is showing up for a second before the data is rendered.

Below is what I have tried until now, have referred to [How to keep scroll position using flatlist when navigating back in react native ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48061234/how-to-keep-scroll-position-using-flatlist-when-navigating-back-in-react-native) , however this is not working as useEffect is not getting called while navigating back to the screen.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useeffect in community called!!!!')
    navigation.addListener('willFocus',()=>{
      const offset=scrollPosition;
      console.log('inside!!!lllllllllllllllllllllll')
      // To prevent FlatList scrolls to top automatically,
      // we have to delay scroll to the original position 
      setTimeout(()=>{
        flatlistRef.scrollToOffset({offset,animated:false})
      },500)
    })
    if (reloadListing || !loadMoreCalled) {
      console.log(
        " Calling Use Effect Community API in SheTalk Listing - reload and load more flags  ",
        reloadListing,
        loadMoreCalled,
      );
      getSheTalkListing();
      // dispatch(setReloadListing(false));
    }
  }, [reloadListing]);

 const handleScroll=(event)=>{
    let yOffset=event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y ;
    setScrollPosition(yOffset)
  }

return(
  <FlatList
              data={mSheTalkList}
              initialNumToRender={10}
              ref={flatlistRef}
              refreshing={false}
              onScroll={(event)=>handleScroll(event)}
              initialScrollIndex={scrollPosition}
              renderItem={({item, index}) => (
                <SLCommunityTabSheTalkListingItemComponent
                  navigation={props.navigation}
                  data={item}
                  key={index}
                  index={index}
                  currentVisibleIndex={currentVisibleIndex}
                  count={index}
                  playButton={onPlayButtonclicked}
                />
              )}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => "key" + index}
              // onEndReached={onEndReached}
              // onEndReachedThreshold={0.8}
              // onMomentumScrollBegin={(onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = false)}
              // onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged.current}
              // viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig.current}
              //viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs={viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs.current}
              viewabilityConfig={{
                viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 90,
              }}
            />
)
```

Any leads would be great. am stuck since long, hope to get hep here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think saving scroll position is a good idea. Keep list page alive.

Comment: you can make details page a modal and add it BackHandler event to close it on back button press. If you still want to make it as you mentioned above then if you'll make a [snack](https://snack.expo.dev) it will be easier to explain the solution.

Comment: @D10S but I need it as a screen itself and not modal

Comment: @gumingfeng could you please elaborate?

Comment: It's quite odd. it should back to the same place it was by default and not to the top. try to remove the initial scroll index and the onscroll props and remove also "flatlistRef.scrollToOffset".

Comment: @D10S it is not working :(

Comment: it's a stack navigation? details and the list are 2 different screens on the same stack?

Comment: Yes, they are two different screens @D10S

Comment: inside a stack navigator?

Comment: Yes in the same       @D10S

Comment: i think this answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/61096298/9444013