# How can i auto focus on an item in ScrollView

Tags: javascript, react-native, uiscrollview

i have an array of posts , and when i click on one of them i want it to take me to a screen containing all the posts but i want it to auto focus on the one that i clicked on before , then after that i can scroll like i want ! is that possible on ScrollView or maybe Flatlist ?

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{}}>
        {posts?.map((post, index) => (
          <View key={index} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Post item={{ ...post, user: item.user }} navigation={navigation} />
          </View>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Its not fully clear, what exactly you want to focus.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient way to scroll to certain index in FlatList with variable item size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57471165/efficient-way-to-scroll-to-certain-index-in-flatlist-with-variable-item-size)